# How to implement a custom thinning algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I need your expertise in this problem: I am currently processing an image and would like to extract the skeleton. So far by means of preprocessing I could reach a skeleton of 2 pixel thickness. However I would really like to minimize the size of the skeleton to end up with a thickness of 1. Therefore I propose the following algorithm,which makes sense to me. Before I start the whole code process, I would like to get rid of some suspicions.
Let me explain:

My algorithm is as follows:

- Scour the image pixels (remember the ROI described acts as a sliding window)
- for the first pixel (skipping boundary pixels) create a region of interest of 3x3 ( the pixel being the anchor(center) of the ROI)
- does that pixel carry a maximum value ? (check this condition using pointers w.r.t its 8 neighbors)
- take at the same time a second 3x3 ROI for the previous pixel's right neighbor
- Is it also a maximum ?

Now create the following logic:

- If the first ROI returns true and the second ROI returns true

  - take the center of the first ROI as true and skip 1 pixel to the right
- If the first ROI return true and the other false

  - take the center of the first ROI true and continue to next pixel

Any other suggestions ? my idea is to get a skeleton of thickness 1.

Comment: Have you looked at the more canonical skeletonization algorithms for inspiration, like Zhang-Suen? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm - This is one of the most popular algorithms.  Also check out Guo-Hall: https://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/

Comment: Thank you @rayryeng I have already seen these two implementations, the problem is I tried to implement the identical functions but since I'm switching between data types, I am getting a lot of crashes. Therefore I decided to implement my own (inefficient in comparison to others) algorithm. I thought if I follow my own algorithm and pay attention to data type conversions, I could reach my goal of creating a skeleton...

Comment: @rayryeng I tried the Zhang Suen algorithm, it resulted in some distortions in critical areas which made my features hard to define. I need a better thinning algorithm that conserves structure